# Reviewing a flagged question should allow me to flag Exact Duplicates even when I'm out of close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, flags

As we know, it's B[y-Design that flags for closing as exact duplicates are converted to close votes when the person has the power to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91837/vote-to-close-or-flag-exact-duplicates-or-both).  All is as it should be.

#### Problem

However, when that person runs out of close votes, they can no longer flag exact duplicates (that option is taken away). I believe this to be sub-optimal, as I have to manually type in (`exact duplicate of : x`).  I realize that I'm probably at the high end of this, since I've been trying to use up my close votes and flag votes every day.

#### Expected Behavior

When a person has used up all their close votes for the day, the option to 'flag as a duplicate' should allow them to 'flag as a duplicate', instead of being gone entirely.

If this is unintentional, it's a bug; if it's intentional, consider this a feature request.  Also, if anyone has any salient points they'd like to bring up on the subject, that would be most welcome.

Comment: None of the close options get converted to flags, not just the close as duplicate

Comment: @ChrisF Yup, and I think that (at least) the exact duplicate case should. I'd be really glad if they all did, but I'l settle for that one, as it's the most common case I've found.

Comment: This is bugging me also. It would be important to at least have the ability to flag when I have no close votes left. Now that you were elected as a mod, can't you just somehow raise this issue?

Comment: I'm just curious, since I can't find anything in search but I'm sure it's a duplicate, has it been asked to give more flags in review queues?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think flagging these helps anything. The purpose of allowing flag-to-close was to give folks who *can't* flag a way to help - albeit with some additional oversight. You really don't need that.

This seems like a cludgy stand-in for simply giving you more close votes. If you can come up with a better system for doing *that*, suggest it.

Otherwise... When you run out of close votes<sup>*</sup>, just leave a comment on the question linking to the existing question, and maybe come back the next day to vote if it's still open. If nothing else, this at least gives the OP a hint that there's an exiting answer to be had.

<sup>*<sub>Ok, so you're a mod with infinite close votes now, but *in general...*</sub></sup>